# method getElementsByTagName is undefined for type element

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to write a Java code for parsing an XML file. I want to retrieve value of all "name" elements inside "function" tag. But when I'm using  NodeList nlList = element.getElementsByTagName("name"); there is error "method getElementsByTagName is undefined for type element".

this is my XML file sample:
Each function tag include multiple "name" elements which I want to use the getTextContent to access the value of these nodes.

```
                <function><type><specifier>private</specifier> <name>boolean</name></type> <name>canClose</name><parameter_list>(<param><decl><type><name>IEditorReference</name></type> <name>editorReference</name></decl></param>)</parameter_list> <block>{
                        <decl_stmt><decl><type><name>IEditorPart</name></type> <name>editor</name> =<init> <expr><call><name><name>editorReference</name>.<name>getEditor</name></name><argument_list>(<argument><expr><name>false</name></expr></argument>)</argument_list></call></expr></init></decl>;</decl_stmt>
                        <if>if <condition>(<expr><name>editor</name> <name>instanceof</name> <name>IContextAwareEditor</name></expr>)</condition><then> <block>{
                            <return>return <expr>((<name>IContextAwareEditor</name>) <name>editor</name>).<call><name>canClose</name><argument_list>()</argument_list></call></expr>;</return>
                        }</block></then></if>
                        <return>return <expr><name>true</name></expr>;</return>
                    }</block></function>
```

This is my code, first I tried to retrieve all of "function" elements and after that I wrote a for loop to find all of "name" elements inside "function" tags.

But there is s error ""method getElementsByTagName is undefined for type element" when I used getElementsByTagName method  for second time.

```
String name = file.getName();
File fXmlFile = new File(dirPath + name);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("function");
for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
    NodeList nList1 = nList.item(temp).getChildNodes();
    Node n = nList1.item(temp);
    if (n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element eElement = (Element) n;
        NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName("name");
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line does it say the error was on, and which line is that in what you've shown us? If it's really saying "type element" -- lowercase -- then you're using a class called element which is not the same thing as an Element and doesn't support that method.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran this snippet :

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("name");
for(int i=0; i<nList.getLength(); i++){
    System.out.println(nList.item(i).getTextContent());
}
```

I got this output:

```
boolean
canClose
IEditorReference
editorReference
IEditorPart
editor

editorReference
.
getEditor

editorReference
getEditor
false
editor
instanceof
IContextAwareEditor
IContextAwareEditor
editor
```

I hope you are trying to achieve the same thing.
Also make sure you import the following in your program. (because you dont wanna import javax.swing.text.Document) :

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I don't want all of the name elements. I just want those who are inside function tags.I have different tags in my XML file which I copied just function tags here.So I don't want the name elements which are inside different tags, I just want those who are inside function tags.

Comment: were you able to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Came across this error, and it turns out I was importing the wrong Element library, therefore it couldn't find the implementation for that function. Make sure you are importing the right library.

```
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
```